# Understanding Rails 6 with multiple database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Rails 6 API
ruby 3
```

This is my first time using Rails with more than one databases but I struggle to understand how it all works. My "playground" is simple:

- A primary database
- A secondary (not a replica)

The secondary database is used for "putting stuff away" and access it whenever needs be.

**database.yml:**

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: primary_development
    password: password
  secondary:
    <<: *default
    database: secondary_development
    password: password
```

Based on the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html), I came up with the above.

Still per docs:

> Now that we have a new database, let's set up the connection model. In order to use the new database we need to create a new abstract class and connect to the animals databases.

```rb
# /models/secondary_record.rb
class SecondaryRecord < ApplicationRecord
    self.abstract_class = true
  
    connects_to database: { writing: :secondary, reading: :secondary }
end
```

And...

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary }
end
```

This is a generic model:

```rb
class Order < SecondaryRecord
    #...
end
```

Everything looks so far. The migration:

```bash
rails g migration create_orders --database secondary
```

Before this setup, I'd already have a "primary" database so I searched online how to connect additional databases. After running `rails db:migrate` my primary database went ahead and create a new `orders` table. I never expected that. More digging I ran, after rolling back:

> rails db:migrate:secondary

This seems better. A new table was created in the `secondary` database. Here's the issue... restarting the server I get an error "migration pending". This is where I'm lost. Can anyone deeply explain how to connect multiple databases and run migrations for a specific database? Do I need to delete the app and start again?

EDIT:

When ran `rails g migration create_orders --database secondary`, it produces:

```rb
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Nothing related to the secondary database with flag `--database secondary`.

Comment: How does that migration look like?

Comment: Hi @SergioTulentsev Ive made an edit.

Comment: Your configuration was insufficient. Your databases share the same `migrations_paths`. Hence that flag `--database secondary` has no effect. Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

Comment: Yes that's correct but here's the issue: `Rails generators now take a --database option so that the file is generated in the correct directory`. This is not working. Everything is under `/db/migrate/<all-migration-files.rb>`

Comment: That's exactly the issue because you haven't configured the directories

Comment: Right? I needed to manually create the dirs? I see.

Comment: I think rails itself should ensure the directories exist. It only needs to know what they are. Give that guide another read.

Comment: `You also need to set the migrations_paths in the database configurations to tell Rails where to find the migrations.`

Comment: Thanks. I have a more thorough read, after I'll confirm.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev All working. Thanks for giving me the clue about `migrations_paths: db/secondary_migrate`